# Issue with form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm new with mysql and php so please bear with me.
I'm trying to connect my first form to a table and I keep running into a new issue every time I "fix" something. I'm trying to test my form to make sure it connects before I move forward.
This is the form:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post">

<p>input 1: <input type="text" name="input1"/></p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

and this is my **"demo.php"** file:

```
<?php

define('BD_NAME', 'DEMO');
define('DB_USER', 'DEMO');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD');
define('DB_HOST', 'HOST');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_close();
?>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Can't use DB_NAME: Access denied for user 'USER'@'%' to database 'DB_NAME'
```

Again I'm new at this and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Did you create user & password for your DB? If not so then use `define('DB_USER', 'root');`
`define('DB_PASSWORD', '');` `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

Comment: @Quentin, I'm new and I'll be moving forward as I go. Thanks! I guess I should learn the latest but it's somewhat harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

`define('BD_NAME', 'DEMO');` should be `define('DB_NAME', 'DEMO');`

Notice the `DB_NAME` global variable that is not resolve :

`Can't use >>>>DB_NAME<<<<: Access denied for user 'USER'@'%' to database 'DB_NAME'`

It means that either `DB_NAME` is not declared OR that the value of `DB_NAME` is "DB_NAME".

Comment: Awesome @Nico !! I can't believe I missed it lol. Nice, it works now. I'm taking any advice and moving into a modern API as suggested. Cheers

Comment: @YarseoLLC np, have a nice day. Like Quentin said, you should use the latest and greatest :)

Answer (score 0):

always use error_reporting(E_ALL) and display errors while coding to avoid these mistakes